# После ротации авл-поддерева поддерево странно изменяется

Tags: c#, .net, рекурсия, дерево

Балансировка работает отлично, но есть у меня странный случай, что когда балансировка дерева вызывается в методе, который был вызван другим, в "другом" методе это дерево отображается очень странно. Видно, что это не связано с областью видимости, ибо дерево все же изменяется. Но в данном случае (см. код), при удалении корня, у меня дерево балансируется таким образом, что 2 элемента просто исчезают из дерева.

Снова напомню: балансировка работает отлично! То есть при отладке я видел, как после всех балансировок дерево принимало идеальный вид, но в другом методе из этого же сбалансированного дерева просто исчезало 2 элемента!

Вот схема как методы относятся друг к другу:

Remove ---> RemoveRec ---> if (root.Right != null && root.Left != null) ---> ---> ReplaceWithSmallest(root, root.Right) ---> root.Right в этом методе хранится как rootSmallest ----> if (после замещения поддерева то, что хранится по ссылке в переменной rootSmallest стало несбалансированным) ---> Balance(rootSmallest) (Балансировка сработала идеально, все сбалансировалось) ---> Возвращаемся к ReplaceWithSmallest() --> переменная rootSmallest которая получает root.Right в качестве аргумента в функции ReplaceWithSmallest() содержит в себе ссылку на ОТЛИЧНО сбалансированное дерево, которое мне нужно ---> возвращаемся к RemoveRec() ↓

> По какой-то причине в RemoveRec переменная root.Right содержит в себе ДРУГОЕ дерево, которое было изменено, но неверно. В то время как root.Right отправлялся в метод, где эта переменная была аргументом "RootSmallest", а RootSmallest содержал в себе то дерево, которое мне и нужно было.

Проблема возникает при удалении корневого элемента, то есть 15. Это второе удаление в методе Main().
Вот код:

```
class Node<T>
{
    internal T value;

    public bool IsBalanced()
    {
        return Math.Abs(Balance) == 0 || Math.Abs(Balance) == 1;
    }

    public int Balance
    {
        get
        {
            if (Left == null && Right == null)
                return 0;
            else if (Left == null && Right != null)
                return -1 - Right.Height;
            else if (Left != null && Right == null)
                return Left.Height + 1;
            return (Left.Height - Right.Height);
        }
        private set { }
    }
    public int Height
    {
        get
        {
            if (Left == null && Right != null)
                return 1 + Right.Height;
            else if (Left != null && Right == null)
                return 1 + Left.Height;
            else if (Left != null && Right != null)
            {
                if (Left.Height >= Right.Height)
                    return Left.Height + 1;
                else
                    return Right.Height + 1;
            }
            else
                return 0;
        }

        private set
        {
        }

    }

    public Node<T> Right;
    public Node<T> Left;
    public Node(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        Right = null;
        Left = null;
    }

    public Node(Node<T> other) // deep copy
    {
        value = other.value;
        Left = other.Left;
        Right = other.Right;
    }

}
class BinarySearchTree<T> where T : IComparable
{
    public Node<T> root;

    public Node<T> Root { get { return root; } set { } }

    public bool IsTreeBalanced()
    {
        return Math.Abs(root.Balance) == 0 || Math.Abs(root.Balance) == 1;
    }

    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return root == null;
    }

    public void InOrder()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        TraversalRec(root);
    }

    public void RotateLeftRight(ref Node<T> root)
    {
        // Double right rotating - Left Right   
        // 1. perform a left rotation on the left subtree
        // 2. rotate the root to the right

        RotateLeft(ref root.Left);
        RotateRight(ref root);
    }

    public void RotateRightLeft(ref Node<T> root)
    {
        // Double left rotation - Right Left
        // 1. perform a right rotation on the right subtree
        // 2. rotate the root to the left

        RotateRight(ref root.Right);
        RotateLeft(ref root);
    }

    public void RotateRight(ref Node<T> root)
    {
        // 1. new root = old root.Left
        // 2. old root.Left = null; old root.Left = old root.Left.Right
        // 3. new root.Right = old root;

        Node<T> newRoot = new Node<T>(root.Left);
        root.Left = root.Left.Right;
        newRoot.Right = new Node<T>(root);
        root = newRoot;

    }

    public void RotateLeft(ref Node<T> root)
    {
        // 1. new root = old root.Right
        // 2. old root.Right = null; old root.Right = old root.Right.Left
        // 3. new root.Left = old root;

        Node<T> newRoot = new Node<T>(root.Right);
        root.Right = root.Right.Left;
        newRoot.Left = new Node<T>(root);
        root = newRoot;
    }

    private void TraversalRec(Node<T> root) // not done yet
    {
        if (root.Left != null)
        {
            TraversalRec(root.Left);
        }
        Console.Write(root.value + " ");
        if (root.Right != null)
        {
            TraversalRec(root.Right);
        }
    }

    public Node<T> Search(T value)
    {
        return SearchRec(value, root);
    }        

    private Node<T> SearchRec(T value, Node<T> root)
    {
        if (root == null)
            return null;
        if (root.value.Equals(value))
            return root;
        else if (root.value.CompareTo(value) > 0)
            return SearchRec(value, root.Left);
        else
            return SearchRec(value, root.Right);
    }

    public bool Add(T value)
    {
        return AddRec(value, ref root);
    }

    private bool AddRec(T value, ref Node<T> root)
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            root = new Node<T>(value);
            return true;
        }
        else if (value.CompareTo(root.value) > 0)
        {
            AddRec(value, ref root.Right);
            if (!root.IsBalanced())
                Rebalance(ref root);
        }
        else if (value.CompareTo(root.value) <= 0)
        {
            AddRec(value, ref root.Left);
            if (!root.IsBalanced())
                Rebalance(ref root);
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void Rebalance(ref Node<T> root)
    {
        int LeftHeight;
        int RightHeight;

        if (root.Left == null)
            LeftHeight = -1;
        else
            LeftHeight = root.Left.Height;

        if (root.Right == null)
            RightHeight = -1;
        else
            RightHeight = root.Right.Height;


        if (LeftHeight > RightHeight) // left case
        {
            int LeftLeftHeight;
            int LeftRightHeight;

            if (root.Left.Left == null)
                LeftLeftHeight = -1;
            else
                LeftLeftHeight = root.Left.Left.Height;

            if (root.Left.Right == null)
                LeftRightHeight = -1;
            else
                LeftRightHeight = root.Left.Right.Height;


            if (LeftLeftHeight > LeftRightHeight) // left left case
            {
                RotateRight(ref root);
            }
            else // left right case
            {   
                RotateLeftRight(ref root);
            }
        }
        else // right case
        {
            int RightRightHeight;
            int RightLeftHeight;

            if (root.Right.Right == null)
                RightRightHeight = -1;
            else
                RightRightHeight = root.Right.Right.Height;

            if (root.Right.Left == null)
                RightLeftHeight = -1;
            else
                RightLeftHeight = root.Right.Left.Height;


            if (RightRightHeight >= RightLeftHeight) // right right case
            {
                RotateLeft(ref root);
            }
            else // right left case
            {
                RotateRightLeft(ref root);
            }
        }
    }




    private void ReplaceWithSmallest(ref Node<T> rootReplace, ref Node<T> rootSmallest) // rootReplace - what to replace, rootSmallest - its right child.
    {
        if (rootSmallest.Left != null)
        {
            ReplaceWithSmallest(ref rootReplace, ref rootSmallest.Left);
            if (!rootSmallest.IsBalanced())
                Rebalance(ref rootSmallest);
        }
        else
        {
            Node<T> newroot = new Node<T>(rootSmallest);
            rootSmallest = rootSmallest.Right;
            newroot.Right = rootReplace.Right;
            newroot.Left = rootReplace.Left;
            rootReplace = newroot;
        } 
    }

    public void Remove(T value)
    {
        RemoveRec(ref root, ref root, value);
    }

    private void RemoveRec(ref Node<T> root, ref Node<T> ParentElem, T value)
    {
        if (root.value.CompareTo(value) == 0) // the element has been found
        {
            if (root.Left != null && root.Right != null)
            {
                ReplaceWithSmallest(ref root, ref root.Right); // replace current root element with the element that this function is going to find (second parameter)                              
            }
            else if (root.Left != null && root.Right == null) // if there's 1 child there
            {
                if (ParentElem.Left.Equals(root)) // if our element is its parent's left son
                    ParentElem.Left = root.Left;
                else
                    ParentElem.Right = root.Left;
            }
            else if (root.Left == null && root.Right != null)
            {
                if (ParentElem.Left.Equals(root))
                    ParentElem.Left = root.Right;
                else
                    ParentElem.Right = root.Right;
            }
            else if (root.Left == null && root.Right == null)
                root = null;
        }
        else if (value.CompareTo(root.value) > 0) // if the value we're looking for is bigger than current element
        {
            RemoveRec(ref root.Right, ref root, value);     // then go to its right child
            if (!root.IsBalanced())
                Rebalance(ref root);
        }
        else if (value.CompareTo(root.value) < 0)
        {
            RemoveRec(ref root.Left, ref root, value); // otherwise go to its left child
            if (!root.IsBalanced())
                Rebalance(ref root);
        }
    }
}
class IntBinarySearchTree : BinarySearchTree<int>
{
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        IntBinarySearchTree A = new IntBinarySearchTree();
        int[] A_array = { 17, 12, 10, 15, 14, 16, 21, 19, 27 };
        for (int i = 0; i < A_array.Length; i++)
            A.Add(A_array[i]);

        A.Remove(10);
        A.InOrder();
        A.Remove(15);
        A.InOrder();
        Console.WriteLine(A.root.Balance);
        Console.WriteLine(A.root.Left.Height);
        Console.WriteLine(A.Root.Right.Height);
















        /*
        // TEST



        // LEFT LEFT = {10, 15, 5, -10, -20} A
        // root.left = -10, root.right = 15, root.left.left = -20, root.left.right = 5

        // LEFT RIGHT = {10, 15, 5, -10, -5} B
        // root.left = -5, root.left.right = 5, root.left.left = -10


        // RIGHT RIGHT = {10, 20, 30, 40, -5} C
        // root.left = -5, root.right = 30, root.right.right = 40, root.right.left = 20

        // RIGHT LEFT = {10, -5, 20, 40, 30} D
        // root.left = -5, root.right = 30, root.right.right = 40, root.right.left = 20


        IntBinarySearchTree A = new IntBinarySearchTree();
        IntBinarySearchTree B = new IntBinarySearchTree();
        IntBinarySearchTree C = new IntBinarySearchTree();
        IntBinarySearchTree D = new IntBinarySearchTree();

        int[] A_values = { 10, 15, 5, -10, -20 };
        int[] B_values = { 10, 15, 5, -10, -5 };
        int[] C_values = {10, 20, 30, 40, -5};
        int[] D_values = { 10, -5, 20, 40, 30 };

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            A.Add(A_values[i]);
            B.Add(B_values[i]);
            C.Add(C_values[i]);
            D.Add(D_values[i]);
        }

        //Console.WriteLine($"AVL TREE 'A':\n root left = {A.root.Left.value} root right = {A.root.Right.value} root.left.left = {A.root.Left.Left.value} root.Left.Right = {A.root.Left.Right.value}");
        //Console.WriteLine($"AVL TREE 'B':\n root.left = {B.root.Left.value}, root.left.right = {B.root.Left.Right.value}, root.left.left = {B.root.Left.Left.value}");
        //Console.WriteLine($"AVL TREE 'C':\n root.left = {C.root.Left.value}, root.right = {C.root.Right.value}, root.left.left = {C.root.Left.Left.value}, root.right.right = {C.root.Right.Right}");
        C.InOrder();
        //Console.WriteLine($"AVL TREE 'D':\n root.left = {D.root.Left.value}, root.right = {D.root.Right.value}, root.right.right = {D.root.Right.Right.value}, root.right.left = {D.Root.Right.Left.value}");
        */




        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```